# Convert char* in hex to normal char*?

Tags: c, string, hex

i have this function:

```
char *ctohex(char *str){
    int i=0, len;
    len = strlen(str);
    char *final = malloc(len*2*sizeof(char)+1);
    while(len--){
         sprintf(final+i*2, "%02X", str[i]);
         i++;
    }
    return final;
}
```

Now i want a reverse function, from hex to normal char, is that possible? Sorry for my english.No one gives me a good answer, maybe i explained wrong.

I have this input at my function:
`JOAO`
output is:
`4A4F414F`

I want to put `4A4F414F` back to `JOAO`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much a simple reverse of the original `ctohex()`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *hextoc(const char *str) {
  size_t i, j, len;
  len = strlen(str);

  // If the length is not even
  if (len % 2)
    return NULL;

  char *final = malloc(len/2 + 1);
  if (final == NULL)
    return NULL;

  j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    if (!isxdigit((unsigned char) str[i])
            || !isxdigit((unsigned char) str[i+1])) {
      free(final);
      return NULL;
    }
    unsigned x;
    sscanf(&str[i], "%2X", &x);
    final[j++] = (char) x;
  }
  final[j] = '\0';
  return final;
}

int main() {
  return puts(hextoc("4A4F414F"));
  // prints JOAO
}
```

---

`ctohex(char *str)` has a problem. when `str[i]` is < 0

```
// sprintf(final+i*2, "%02X", str[i]);
sprintf(final+i*2, "%02X", str[i] & 0xFF);
// or
sprintf(final+i*2, "%02hhX", str[i]);  // Current C compilers
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course converting from hex to normal char is possible.

Examine 2 characters at a time and decide what char to print

```
if (char1 == '0' && char2 == '0') putchar(0x00);
if (char1 == '0' && char2 == '1') putchar(0x01);
/* ... */
if (char1 == '4' && char2 == '2') putchar(0x42); /* ASCII B */
/* ... */
if (char1 == 'f' && char2 == 'f') putchar(0xff);
```

There are more efficicent ways to do it though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use strtol() with base=16 on each of your hex numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you your conversion to hex isn't really doing anything, as you are converting each digit to its hex equivalent, which does nothing.  5 in decimal is also 5 in hex.  All you did is put 0's between each digit ("5432" -> "05040302")

If you are asking to take a number in a string that is represented by its hex value and put it into a string as its decimal value, e.g. "0x5A8C" -> "23180", then this is what you do:

```
    char *convert( char * instr )
    {
        char outstr[50] = {0};
        int tmpval = 0;
        sscanf( instr, "%x", tmpval );
        sprintf( outstr, "%d", tmpval );
        char * retval;
        strcpy( retval, outstr );
        return retval;
    }
```

The benefit of using sscanf() is that sscanf will treat `0x5a`, `0X5A`, `5a`, and `5A` the same.

If you are just trying to convert back any string that is generated by your ctohex() function, then you just need to copy every other digit into a new string.

If you want to convert a sequence of hex digits into decimal values, then you have to specify how many digits are getting converted.  Do you want "5A8C" -> "510812" or do you want "90140"?